# Deployment Error “Summarized field must be on an object that is a detail of object containing summary”

Tags: deployment, error, roll-up-summary

I receive the following error message

> “Summarized field must be on an object that is a detail of object containing summary”

when deploying a roll-up summary field.

Created a brand new rollup summary field. The field is fine in sandbox, but complains when I deploy it to production.

Please advise how to avoid such error and be able to deploy it on my production org?

Comment: Does the summarized field on the detail object already exist in Production, or have you included it in your deployment?

Comment: No there is no summarized field on Production.  Yes, I have included it into my deployment

Comment: On the sandbox the relationship is Master-Detail, but is it on the production instance as well? You won't be able to deploy it unless the relationship on the target org is also a Master-Detail one. So you might want to deploy the child object's field that references the master object too.

Answer (score 1):

it may be too late to respond to your question.
Maybe somebody else needs the answer too.

*Ans*: *Please make sure that the child object was deployed and contain the master-detail field.*

*Ex: I have deployed credit object which is a child object of the account first, then I can deploy the account roll-up field.*